# How to declare a constraint to limit the number of holding foreign object?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have 2 table,
Owner(oid, name)
Dog(name, oid), where foreign key Dog (oid) references Owner (oid)

I want to know how to set a constraint so that Owner can only own at most 2 Dogs?

Comment: you need to use a trigger

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are looking for with a trigger which blocks insertion of a third dog for the same owner.

> ```
> create table owner(
> id int primary key,
> name varchar(10) );
> ```

> ```
> create table dog(
> name varchar(10) primary key,
> oid int ,
> constraint fk_dog_owner foreign key 
>      (oid) references owner(id) );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER dog_max_two
> BEFORE INSERT ON dog
>     FOR EACH ROW 
> DECLARE
>   dogCount number(10);
> BEGIN 
>   Select count(name) INTO dogCount
>   From dog where oid = :NEW.oid;
>   IF( dogCount > 1 )
>     THEN
>       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001,
>         'maximum 2 dogs per person');
>   END IF;
> END;
> /
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO owner VALUES (1,'Bill');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dog VALUES ('Rover', 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dog VALUES ('Boy', 1);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dog VALUES ('Alfie', 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-20001: maximum 2 dogs per person
> ```

ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_HZTJGHLANPRDIFXWPMZS.DOG_MAX_TWO", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_HZTJGHLANPRDIFXWPMZS.DOG_MAX_TWO'

> 

> ```
> select * from dog;
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME  | OID
> :---- | --:
> Rover |   1
> Boy   |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e3e795b35bee81ea53d311d923a7910)*